# iPhone app stopped at <????> in Debug navigator

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, sdk

When i run iPhone application after some time app stopped and in debug navigator i see that app stopped at '<'????'>'.
What mean when my app stopped at '<'????'>' in Debug navigator?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Enable [NSZombie](http://iphonedevelopertips.com/debugging/tracking-down-exc_bad_access-errors-with-nszombieenabled.html) and track down the exact place where the app crashes.

Answer (score 0):

Can you re-word your question? I don't understand.. What do you mean it "stopped" at 0? What other information was given in the debugger?